# How can I count only the sublists having more than 9 number of '2'?

Tags: list-manipulation

I made a table giving me 1's and 2's

```
In[23]:= S = Join[Table[1, 1], Table[2, 1]]
```

Out[23]= {1, 2}

And then I made it bigger:

```
T = RandomChoice[S, 15*365];
```

And then I separated it:

```
R = Partition[T, 15];
```

It looks something like this:

```
{{2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
  1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
  2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
  2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
  1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 
  2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
  1, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 
  2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
  1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
  1}, {2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
  1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
  1, 2, 2},
```

but much bigger.
I want to count the number of sublists with more than 9 2's only. 
Is there anyway to do this? Is there a way to treat the sublists as a separate unit, as opposed to the entire list of R?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use uppercase initials for your symbols: you will eventually end up clashing with some built-in.
`Tr[UnitStep[Total[R - 1, {2}] - 10]]` will quickly do what you want.

Comment: Jus use this for `R= RandomChoice[{1,2}, {365,15}];`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you ... let your list be called `r`, then try

```
Count[Map[Count[#, 2] > 9 &, r], True]
```

If you need further explanation, ask for it.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you!

Comment: Slightly simpler: `Count[r, x_ /; Count[x, 2] > 9]`

Comment: Also `Length[Select[r, Count[#, 2] > 9 &]]`

Answer (score 0):

Just another way for this specific context:

```
r = Partition[RandomChoice[{1, 2}, 15 365], 15];
Count[Total /@ (r - 1), _?(# > 9 &)]
```

However, as comments illustrate there are many ways to do this.